# What is the proper way to exclude multiple specific numbers from a set?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm working on some homework, and my google-fu isn't helping me out with this question. I've already solved it, but I need to put it into the proper notation in order to get full credit. I've already figured out that the range is $[-5,\infty)$, but I can't figure out the proper notation, nothing looks right to me. I feel like the answer should be $\mathbb R\setminus \{(-\infty, -5)\}$ ?

(the question in question:  Find the largest possible subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$ that will make the following functions well-defined.  $A\to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x) = \sqrt{3x+15}$: The range where the question is well defined is from $-5$ to infinity, but I don't know how to "formally" say it.

Comment: For what i understand you want to know where that funciton is defined, just use the fact where the square root function is defined in $3x+15$

Comment: $x\in[-5,\infty)$ means $-5\le x$; the symbol ``\`` is usually   `\setminus`, so  $\mathbb R\setminus(-\infty, -5)$ is a more cumbersome way of writing the same thing as $[-5,\infty)$

Comment: Didn't paste properly aparently, doesn't like words equation editor I guess.  A of R

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site.

Comment: got it, the next time I need to post something I'll figure out MathJax and post my question!

Comment: I don't understand. Didn't you give the answer in the question itself? You wrote that the answer is $[-5, \infty)$. So that's the notation.

Comment: Simply put, I have never taken Discrete Mathematics before. Nor have I ever purchased the textbook for the class. I try to substitute this knowledge with extensive use of google. Because the proper notation is so blisteringly simple, I didn't think it was the proper notation, and felt the need to ask a question about it.

Comment: Can't you do something like: $(a-c, a+c) \backslash \{a, 0, 4\}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x) = \sqrt{3x+15}$$

This function is well-defined on $[-5,\infty)$, just as you wrote. That was already the correct final notation. You could also write $[-5,\infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$, or you could write $\mathbb{R}\setminus (-\infty,-5)$.

But $\{(-\infty,-5)\}$ is the set containing an interval, not the interval itself. You could write $\{x \in (-\infty,-5)\}$, but that is equivalent to $(-\infty,-5)$.

Finally, the word "range" when involving functions means the set of possible outputs of a function. From context clues, I gather that you mean "interval" when you used the word range. That is a more appropriate term in this context.